# Save an entity and it's related entity in one save in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an entity `Period`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "period")
public class Period implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "day_of_week")
    private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private LocalTime startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private LocalTime endTime;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "period" }, allowSetters = true)
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private Periodicity periodicity;
```

and it's related entity `Periodicity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "periodicity")
public class Periodicity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "periodicity_label")
    private TypeOfPeriodicity periodicityLabel;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private LocalTime endTime;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "periodicity", "resource" }, allowSetters = true)
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "periodicity")
    private Period period;
```

also an enum `TypeOfPeriodicity`:

```
public enum TypeOfPeriodicity {
    JOURNALIER,
    HEBDOMADAIRE,
    MENSUEL,
    SEMESTRIEL,
    TRIMESTRIEL,
    ANNUEL,
}
```

On the font end when creating a new period, I specify the TypeOfPeriodicity for that Period. On the back end, I want to take that TypeOfPeriodicity and endTime from Period and also save a new Periodicity at the same time using those attributes.
Any idea how to do this? I need help.

Answer (score 0):

In the period class you could use `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)` to make hibernate persist the Periodicity entity when saving the Period entity.
See https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types for more info about what CascadeType type does, generally ALL is used though

Comment: I think this method won't work, in my case TypeOfPeriodicity is not a direct attribute of period.